# Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $K$ and $f: V \to W$ a Homomorphism. Prove that this is a Homomorphism: $f^*: V^* \to W^*, g \to g \circ f$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields, group-homomorphism

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $K$  and $f: V \to W$ a Homomorphism. Prove that this is a Homomorphism.
$$f^*: V^* \to W^*, g \to g \circ f$$

---

My attempt:

Homomorphism means
$f(\alpha v + w) = \alpha f(v) + f(w)$

And we have

$g \circ f = g(f(x))$

Somehow we must get

$g \circ f(\alpha v + w) = \alpha (g \circ f)(v) + (g \circ f)(w)$

but how ? Any hint would be welcome.

Comment: @Student Yes that's what I wrote ? We don't necessarily need to write $\beta w$ if we already check the scalar for $\alpha v$, do we ?

Comment: The map is not correctly defined.

Comment: You will get a map from W* to V* ,  pre composing by f

Comment: Plus, what you have written checks that $g \circ f$ is a homomorphism, not that $f^*$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Maybe it would help to add your definition of $V^*$ and your attempts at simplifying $g \circ f (\alpha v + w)$ to the question.

Comment: @ronno Isn't $f^* = g \circ f$ ? It isn't written what the star means.

Comment: No, $f^*(g) = g \circ f$. You should start by writing down the domains and codomains of all the maps involved.

Comment: $f^*:W^*\to V^*$ is linear, since $(\forall g,h\in W^*)\;f^*(\alpha g+h)=\alpha f^*(g)+f^*(h)$ i.e. $(\alpha g+h)\circ f=\alpha(g\circ f)+(h\circ f)$, by definition of $+$ and $\alpha\cdot$ on $W^*$ and on $V^*.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Does the star (*) indicate that it's a dual map/space ? I'm a bit confused because it isn't written in the exercise what the star means, and I don't remember we had it in lecture, so after looking up online, I found that it could show a dual map/space, and one of its property is that it is linear, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, $V^*=L(V,K).$ Does this answer your question? [Proving the transpose / dual map is well defined.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593914/proving-the-transpose-dual-map-is-well-defined) (though it was not asked by the OP, the accepted answer proves the linearity of your $f^*$, ususally denoted by $f^t$, the transpose map of $f$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much. So just to be sure, this exercise basically uses the fact that (*) (likely) shows it's a dual map. And one of its properties is that it is linear. So using this property, we can show it's a Homomorphism. So we don't actually prove much, we just go back on the definition of a linear map/space, and use that to show it's a Homomorphism. Is that correct ?

Comment: No.  $(^*)$ "shows" nothing, it is just a notation. And you are *not allowed to use* that this "dual map" (usually called transpose map) is a homomorphism (i.e. is linear, from the (dual) vector space $W^*$ to the (dual) vector space $V^*$), since you are precisely *asked to prove it*. It is not "by definition". There is something to prove. The proof is in my first comment above, and (in more detail) in the linked post.